# Adding text to a textview using a function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to add text to a textview without using a button and I keep getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) when the aButton is pressed. The error brings me to the myTextView.text = "" line. The posts that I have found regarding the error thus far which is this one What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean? are great if your problem is a declared variable which you can fix by using the if let method but the answer becomes a lot more difficult when it pertains to adding text to a textview.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
var textArray: [String] = []
@IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView! 
     func addText()
{
  myTextView.text = ""

   for words in textArray
  {
  myTextView.textStorage.append(NSAttributedString(string: words))
  }
}
 @IBAction func aButton(_ sender: Any)
  {
   textArray.append("a ")
   ViewController().addText()
  }
}
```

Comment: why `ViewController().addText()` ?? why not `self.addText() `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

the optional value is nil means your IBOutlet weak variable "myTextView" is nil, calling a method on a nil, this crashes your app.

as you add textView by using StoryBoard, it needs some prepare job before your outlet is connected or useable to your code named "ViewController" , such as load and create object from nib file

[for more info about nib file](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html)

and what's more, cause you are calling addText method in a new ViewController object, even there is no error at all, it will not change the textView on the screen, cause they are different object. like @Bilal said, use self.addText() or addText() will be OK.

last, debuger is your best friend

Comment: Thanks man, I've been at this for a day or so now and just couldn't grasp what was going on. You simplified it for me in a way that made a lot of sense.

Comment: Quick question, How would I call the addText() function from a view?

Comment: you may use the extension feature, just add addText method to the extension block of that view, then call it like someView.addText()

Comment: I did that and now I am getting the same old error about trying to unwrap nil. Heres what i got so far 
extension ViewController
{
    func addText2()
    {
        myTextView.text = ""
        
        for words in textArray
        {
            myTextView.textStorage.append(NSAttributedString(string: words))
        }
    }
}
class Slide: UIView {
    
    @IBAction func nobodyButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
            textArray.append("nobody ")
            ViewController().addText2()
        }
}

Comment: add a method by extension does not save you from nil crash, even you can call addText method from a view, but the killer reason is that IBOutlet not ready for use, why not call addText method on the ViewController itself, if you are still confused, some tutorial on Youtube or Apple's programming guide may really help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Writing `ViewController().addText()` means that you are creating the new instance of your class ViewController rather than you should use `self.addText()`

Answer (score 0):

```
    @IBOutlet weak var txtView: UITextView! //your textView
    var textArray: [String] = []

    func addText() //function
        {
            txtView.text = "" //your textView
            for words in textArray
            {
                txtView.textStorage.append(NSAttributedString(string: words))
            }
        }


    //Action 

    @IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

            textArray.append("a ")
            addText()//call your function
    }

I hope, its work for you!
```